# Accelerometer and Gyroscope Multiple Values - DJI iOS UXSDKDemo

Tags: objective-c, dji-sdk, telemetry

Is there a way to get the accelerometer and gyroscope sensor data from all three axises (xyz)? Using the code below, I consistently log the "LOG: Gyroscope: 5.0000" or "LOG: Gyroscope: 6.0000". The same result occurs for the accelerometer. Why is it outputting only one value instead of three for each of the axises? Also, why are the values exactly 5 and 6 consistently? Shouldn't there be much more variation?

```
//GYROSCOPE
    DJIFlightControllerKey *IMUStateGyroscopeStateForLog = [DJIFlightControllerKey keyWithParam:DJIFlightControllerParamIMUStateGyroscopeState];

// Will get called once to get current value of the key
[[DJISDKManager keyManager] getValueForKey:IMUStateGyroscopeStateForLog withCompletion:^(DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable value, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];

// Called only when the value for the key changes
[[DJISDKManager keyManager] startListeningForChangesOnKey:IMUStateGyroscopeStateForLog withListener:self andUpdateBlock:^(DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable oldValue, DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable newValue) {
    NSLog(@"LOG: Gyroscope: %f", newValue.doubleValue);
    }];




//ACCELEROMETER
DJIFlightControllerKey *IMUStateAccelerometerStateForLog = [DJIFlightControllerKey keyWithParam:DJIFlightControllerParamIMUAccelerometerState];

// Will get called once to get current value of the key
[[DJISDKManager keyManager] getValueForKey:IMUStateAccelerometerStateForLog withCompletion:^(DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable value, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];

// Called only when the value for the key changes
[[DJISDKManager keyManager] startListeningForChangesOnKey:IMUStateAccelerometerStateForLog withListener:self andUpdateBlock:^(DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable oldValue, DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable newValue) {
    NSLog(@"LOG: Accelerometer: %f", newValue.doubleValue);
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've looked into this issue some more.  The values you are logging are overall states of the IMU and the Gyro that are declared in an enum hence why you aren't getting a constant state of values you are looking for.  It appears to be a bug on our end that this data isn't available.

Comment: Ok, I am having a similar problem with velocity (DJIFlightControllerParamVelocity). Only zeros are returned for this value despite the fact that a horizontal velocity is displayed on the iOS device. Is this also a problem on DJI's end?

Comment: Oh, and the same for DJIFlightControllerParamAircraftLocation?

Comment: @brayvan To get the speed in each direction you have to access the vector it returns like this: DJISDKVector3D *speedVector = value.value;  This is a cartesian vector in 3D Space that returns the X component, Y component and Z component.

Comment: @brayvan to get the value from DJIFlightControllerParamAircraftLocation you have to get the value using CLLocation *location = value.value;  From this CLLocation has the lat/long.

Comment: @brayvan https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/KeyManager/DJIFlightControllerKey.html?search=djiflightcontrollerparamvelocity&i=4&#djiflightcontrollerkey_djiflightcontrollerparamvelocity_key here is our API reference for FlightControllerKeys that you can see the return type of every key.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this: DJISDKVector3D *speedVector = [[DJISDKVector3D alloc]init];         NSDate *date = [NSDate date];       NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@, %f, %f, %f", date, speedVector.x, speedVector.y, speedVector.z]; But this only printed zeros. I am I not correctly initializing the speedVector? Does it need to "listen" like the other keys did?

Comment: @brayvan you need to do a listen like the other keys then create the vector inside of the completion block like DJISDKVector3D *speedVector = value.value;

Comment: Great! That worked. I just had to change DJISDKVector3D *speedVector = value.value; to DJISDKVector3D *speedVector = newValue.value;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173169/discussion-between-brayvan-and-russfenenga).